# Delete random registry key

Tags: powershell, batch-file, registry

I'm trying to write a script, batch or ps to delete a randomly generated registry key.  My idea was to find the key by searching for a static value under that key through a batch file.  I can successfully find and return a value with this search:

REG Query HKLM\Software\Classes\Installer\Products /F "searchterm" /S

The randomly generated key would be directly after "\Products".  The reg query returns this:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\Installer\Products\RANDOMKEY

Product Name  REG_SZ searchterm

I need to delete RANDOMKEY and everything beneath it.  How can I capture that RANDOMKEY in a variable, so that I can then send it to a delete command?  If Powershell is a better tool to solve this, I'd be happy to hear those suggestions too.

Thank you!

Comment: How would you know what the random key was?

Comment: If you place an issue like this I can only repeat the warning from Microsoft: [**Warning Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly by using Registry Editor or by using another method. These problems might require that you reinstall the operating system. Microsoft cannot guarantee that these problems can be solved. Modify the registry at your own risk.**](https://support.microsoft.com/help/256986/windows-registry-information-for-advanced-users). What if there are multiple keys under `Installer\Products`? See also: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a `For /F` loop fo get this information into a variable.

````
@(SetLocal
  Echo off 
  SET "_Key="
)

FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%_ IN ('
  REG Query HKLM\Software\Classes\Installer\Products /F "searchterm" /S
') DO (
  ECHO= Found Value "%%~_"
  SET "_Key=%%~_"
)

ECHO=Only the fibal value is retained outside the loop
ECHO=
ECHO=So the result _Key is "%_Key%"
Echo=
ECHO= If that is ths correct value you needed we can write a part that goes here to delete it.
PAUSE
```
````